# Filling data in response cards with Amazon Lex

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I figured out how to send a Close response that would send details to the user and close the intent.But I can't figure out how to mange other types of comunication from the lambda to the dialog flow.

A.How can I send custom values or information that would appear in the response message so the user could chose ?.

Basiclly I think that I am asking for a custom slot configuaration through the lambda, based on the user choises.

B.Specifically I am also trying to send (or configure) custom values in response card through the lambda.
Those values would be selected in the lambda function based on the user choises so far during the dialog. How can I do that ?

Comment: Can't really help you with the specifics of C# but have you looked through this? https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/bots-just-got-better-net-toolkit-lex-lambda-cognito/module-two/

Comment: Can you share the code of sending the response card to the user?